# Access network setting within app

Tags: iphone, ios, network-programming

Im doing some research for an upcoming project and I am wondering if it is possible to have access to the users iPhone network settings from within the app. In other words, can the iPhone share network settings with the app?

Comment: No, iOS doesn't allow you to read wifi or data network related settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible. You must go through the apple settings menu's etc. You can open the network settings using a link from your app

Comment: Opening network settings with a link is unfortunately not possible from iOS 5.1 on.